# What's a ED, EIC, and ADM?

Tags: publications, publishers, titles

I submitted a journal article for publication and peer-review is taking much much longer than is typical for the journal I submitted to.  In the manuscript submission portal there is a link to contact the journal.  When I follow the link it asks me who I want to send the message to.  My options are the ED, EIC, or ADM but I am not sure what these three acronyms stand for.  Can someone fill me in on what these acronyms stand for and who would be the best choice to follow-up on with my manuscript?

Comment: Please write to the journal when this happens, do not ask on the internet. If they have to answer many questions, maybe this will motivate them to improve their subpar pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically ED is your *editor* and you've probably communicated with them before. EIC is the *editor in charge*; in charge of other editors. ADM is probably the *administration* and contacting them would be appropriate for things other than review process in most cases.

The ED(itor) is probably the one most familiar with your situation so is most likely to be helpful in a hurry. If you don't get satisfaction there, the EIC might work, though it will take longer as they need to communicate with the ED anyway.

---

See the following for a description of the editorial process: [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like? How should I interpret a particular submission status?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/75368)